# How to check creation date of postgres schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-schema, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

For debugging purposes I would like to know when are some of my postgres schemas created at- is it possible?

Searched from PostgreSQL and Apartment docs but didn't find any helpful clues.

**Environment and tools I'm using:**

```
+---------------+----------+
| Tools         | Version  |
+--------------------------+
| PostgreSQL    | 9.4.1    |
| Ruby          | 2.2.1p85 |
| Ruby on Rails | 4.1.9    |
| Apartment gem | 0.26.1   |
+---------------+----------+
```

As you can see I use [Apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) for creating schemas in my multi-tenant rails application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL system catalogs don't store the dates on which database objects were created. You *can* configure PostgreSQL to log more or less every SQL statement ([log_statement setting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT)), but you'd have had to do that beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an [event trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createeventtrigger.html) and store the date of this event in a table. And example can be found [here](http://www.youlikeprogramming.com/2013/10/implementing-ddl-event-triggers-in-postgresql-9-3/)

Answer (score 0):

I'll post a "**Rails way**" solution that will not work for previously made schemas but new-ones.

1. Create model for tenants `rails g model Tenant name:string`
2. Add [after_create callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#creating-an-object) for Tenant model

   ```
   class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base
     after_create :tenant_moves_in

     private

     def tenant_moves_in
       Apartment::Tenant.create self.name
     end
   ```
3. For ex. create somekind of script for making tenants or use ActiveRecord [CRUD](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#crud-reading-and-writing-data) ability with Tenant model to operate with tenants in your app directly like `Tenant.create(name: 'new_tenant')`.

Thatway you can have created_at and updated_at dates in your db tenants table in relation to Apartment Tenants, which represent postgres schemas.

Of course then you should avoid making tenants with Aparmtent tool like `Apartment::Tenant.create 'new_tenant'` because that will not create a Tenant-model object and therefore no created_at time will be preserved.

Answer (score -1):

**Disclamer : This answers a wrong interpretation of the question.
I keep it in case it is useful for someone...**

When you run you Ruby on Rails migrations with `rake db:migrate`, rails maintain a file witch shows you a snapshot of the database structure. This file is in `db/schema.rb`.

Here is an example of a table with a `created_at` added by rails :

```
  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
    t.string   "origin",     default: "web"
  end
```

More details here:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Comment: If I understand you properly then that's not quite the case. `db/schema.rb` holds, yes, the structure of database schema, but it does not contain information about *multiple different* schemas I've made. As much as I know, it only shows the date of last made new migration. 
`created_at` field in table is for holding information about when *an object of that table* is created not the table itself. 
Also migrations run automatically after creating new schema (which I do like this: `Apartment::Tenant.create 'new_schema_name'`)

Comment: You are right, I have misunderstood your problem. Sorry I have no solution for that.